# Zend Framework possibly creating backup web pages?

Tags: php, zend-framework, backup, html

I was recently given a project on investigating on how to remove a web application's various vulnerabilities.

The site runs under the Zend Framework just to add.

After a vulnerability assessment was done on the said web site, the result showed that while browsing certain pages in the site, *backup web pages* were made. (These being files having .bak, .bkp, and .old as their file extensions among a few)

I tried logging into the site and browsing to the said pages that were said to create the backup web pages but found nothing when going over the server's directory at the same time.

I'm completely new to Zend and is this natural for the framework? My guess is that Zend creates temporary files but I'm really not sure.

If it does, is this really a vulnerability? 
If it is, how can it be removed?

I've tried searching for it first but it was to no avail.

Comment: It's much more likely that this is your editor/IDE, or perhaps the manual action of a developer who was not using version control. Zend will not do this unless someone has added code specifically to do it.

Comment: I confirm. Zend does not create files on its own. Even if developer was using Zend_Cache module (which creates cache files) they are not using this extensions.

Comment: So is it may be possible that these backup web pages that were seen by the tool are caused by bad coding practices?

Comment: We have tried searching all the codes and so far we have not seen any code that indicates that the page is tasked to create backup files. We have also tried searching our server logs.